# How to write a script which concatenates namedValues?

Tags: google-sheets, substring, concatenation, google-forms

I have a google sheet populated by a google form input with 1 column that has a start date, the 2nd has the start time (the time is a text input from a drop down menu in a time format (but it is text) - 09:00 - 09:30 - 10:00 ..etc) I'm trying to join the date and time input to create a calendar event with the end date the same day as the start day and end time 30 minutes after. Any help would be appreciated!

I have searched and found that the text string for time can be converted  by removing the ' sign infront of the text time input by using:-

```
var withoutQuote = e.values[1].substring(1);
```

My current script for createEvent:-

```
var options = { description: namedValues.Description[0],
              location: namedValues.Location[0],
              guests:"info@domain.com"};
var cEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("TEST")[0].createEvent(
              namedValues.Name[0], 
              new Date(namedValues.Starts), 
              new Date(namedValues.Ends), 
              options)
```

}

I would like to create new date based on input date (namedValues.Starts) + concatenate start time (namedValues.Stime) and new date based on (namedValues.Starts) + concatenate start time (namedValues.Stime) + 30 minutes

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to get the concatenates namedValues part right herewith edit code:-

```
function createEvent_ (namedValues) {
var options = { description: namedValues.Description[0],
              location: namedValues.Location[0],
              guests:"johan@inprint.co.za"};

var cEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("TEST")[0].createEvent(
              namedValues.Name[0], 
              new Date(namedValues.Starts + " " + namedValues.Stime), 
              new Date(namedValues.Ends + " " + namedValues.Etime), 
              options)
}
```

What I need now is the second part - I would like to create a new end date/time  - based on new Date(namedValues.Starts + " " + namedValues.Stime) + 30 minutes